# Can anyone help? PHP send E-Mail with gmail

Tags: php, email, error-handling, gmail

hello i would like to send a confirmation email via my website when you create an account. unfortunately I can't get any further, can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
function send_activation_email($email,$usrnameemail,$code) {
mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP();

  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;  
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = TRUE;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
  $mail->Port       = 587;
  $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->Username   = "XXX";
  $mail->Password   = "XXX";

  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->AddAddress($email, $usrnameemail);
  $mail->SetFrom(mail_from, mail_sender);
  $mail->AddReplyTo(mail_from, mail_sender);
  $mail->AddCC(mail_from, mail_sender);
  $mail->Subject = 'Test Email';
  $content = "<b>This is a Test Email sent via Gmail SMTP Server using PHP mailer class. </b><a href='$code'>Click here to activate your account</a>";
$mail->MsgHTML($content); 
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Error while sending Email.";
  var_dump($mail);
} else {
  echo "Email sent successfully";
}
}
```

Comment: `mail = new PHPMailer();` must be `$mail = new PHPMailer();`.

Comment: Verify your code that you write it correctly. `mail_from` is not variable but `$mail_from` is. However the variable must be defined or set that where its value come from, not just call it or you will get undefined variable error.

Comment: thank you very much that's embarrassing

Answer (score 1):

Today You cannot use the email password you're using when accessing gmail.com to send emails using SMTP.

You should activate/create **App Password**. When done you will got a password that you can use for Your PHP Mailer.

its can help You too, if Your App Password has security breach, You can simply delete that App password and recreate new one.

for reference You can access:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en